# Is this a hyperplane or a half-space in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology, finite-fields

Simple terminological question: the equation $x_1+\dots+x_n = 0$ over $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ is called a subspace. I'm wondering if we could also call it a hyperplane, a half-space or neither?

The equality sign seems to suggest it's a hyperplane, but the fact that it always cuts the space exactly in half seems to suggest it's a half-space. Just curious!

Comment: Usually the term "half-space" is something defined by an inequality (e.g. the half-plane $x_1-x_2 > 0$ inside the real plane $\Bbb{R}^2$). Now, in positive characteristic, this does not make sense, since such fields cannot be ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly a hyperplane – to my mind "hyperplane" is just another word for affine subspace, usually exactly one dimension lower than the enclosing space, as in this case. It's also half a space, but I would find calling it a "half-space" confusing. It doesn't fall under [Wikipedia's definition of a half-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_%28geometry%29), which matches my use of the term: A half of a space separated from the other half by a plane in a symmetric way, either including (closed) or not including (open) that plane, but not *being* that plane.